# External vs Internal resources for war deployments, e.g Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, war, velocity

I have a web app that current uses an external directory to host static files, e.g css, velocity, in a Spring webapp. That is, the directory is inside tomcat's webapp directory but not inside the WAR.

Other than the ability to easily edit these resources without needing to recompile-package-deploy is there any advantage to not including these files inside the war.

I seem to recall being told A LONG TIME AGO that Tomcat had poor performance in serving files static files, but I don't have any experience that backs this up. As far as I'm aware the only advantage is that of ease of editing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'external directory'? Do you already have a web server (like Apache HTTP Server) in place that serves those static files?

Comment: The current setup is Apache HTTPd with the usual connector to Tomcat. The external resources directory is in the same folder as the unexploded WAR. In my ideal world I would just have Tomcat and the war, but I'm curious as to whether the current configuration has any advantages other than easy edit of css/html/velocity/etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the **web server in front of application server** pattern is still valid:

1. *web server* to provide TLS/SSL termination; clients talk to your URL via HTTPS, the web server terminates SSL and forwards plain HTTP messages to your application server (tomcat). In this scenario the *web server* can take over the load caused by encryption (CPU utilization)
2. *web server* to serve static content; when it comes to high traffic sites or sites serving a large amount of static content, the *web server* can provide the static content. Think of an application providing a product catalog which contains high resolution images (say > 1m). Downloading images directly from the *application server* requires one thread on your application server. It also reduces network I/O on your application server node.
3. *web server* in Demilitarized Zone (DMZ); a common pattern in enterprise deployments. The *web server* is hosted in a zone available to the public, whereas your *application server* is hosted in an internal zone available to the *web server* only. This introduces another layer of security.
4. *web server* to provide static caching; *web servers* like Apache are doing well when it comes to caching.

No question, depending on your use case it may look different:

1. you gain most advantage of the examples provided above if your web server resides on a different server node as it's about computing power (CPU in this case).
2. As always *distributed computing* introduces a layer of complexity, deployment and management in this case.
3. establishing identical security approaches on both, *web server* and *application server* may become tricky, e.g. only certain users are allowed to access certain images.

Having *web server* and *application server* on the same nodes reduces the advantages of providing a *web server*. My experience is that when it comes to 'smaller' internal applications used by 'a few users' a web server is not necessary and tomcat serves well. This is especially true if your app only serves some static files like *icons*, *css* and *javascript*.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks that's a really good answer! So currently if I understand correctly in my setup the application server (tomcat) is serving the static resources not the webapp and so I don't have any advantages you've described (caching, reduced intranetwork communication, etc) so really in my case there is no good reason beyond editability. And perhaps I should consider moving the static resources to the web server.

Comment: @SilentICE: I think it depends. If your app works well today, you may not have the need for a web server. If you plan for growth or want to tackle some security issues (DMZ) it may make sense. Using [`mod_jk`](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/index.html) integration is fairly easy.